# Получаю null с сервера

Tags: android, json, retrofit

[image: Скрин Postman]Использую Retrofit, чтобы получить данные о погоде с [сервера](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Makhachkala&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7). Но в `responce.body()` выводится `null`. Подскажите, где ошибка

Класс NetworkRequest

```
    private static NetworkRequest request;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    NetworkRequest() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static NetworkRequest getRequest(){
        if(request == null){
            request = new NetworkRequest();
        }
        return request;
    }

    public WeatherAPI getWeatherApi(){
        return  retrofit.create(WeatherAPI.class);
    }

}
```

Интерфейс WeatherAPI

```
public interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET (""weather?q=Makhachkala&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7"")
    Call<List<Weather>> getWeather();
}
```

Класс-модель Weather

```
public class Weather {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String locale = "Город";

    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private String temperature = "Температура";

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description = "Статус";

    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private String humidity = "Влажность";

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }
    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }
    public void setTemperature(String temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }
    public void setHumidity(String humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView tvLocation = findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        final TextView tvTemperature = findViewById(R.id.tv_temperature);
        final TextView tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        final TextView tvHumidity = findViewById(R.id.tv_humidity);



        NetworkRequest.getRequest()
                .getWeatherApi()
                .getWeather()
                .enqueue(new Callback<List<Weather>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Weather>> call, Response<List<Weather>> response) {
                        System.out.println("вывелось - " + response.body());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Weather>> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну судя по тому что отдает этот запрос на [api.openweathermap.org](https://openweathermap.org/current) вы просто неверно построили модель. Я запустил их [тестовый пример](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Makhachkala,RU/main&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7) по вашему запросы и там приходит вот такой ответ:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 145.77,
        "lat": -16.92
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 802,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "scattered clouds",
            "icon": "03n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 300.15,
        "pressure": 1007,
        "humidity": 74,
        "temp_min": 300.15,
        "temp_max": 300.15
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 3.6,
        "deg": 160
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 40
    },
    "dt": 1485790200,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 8166,
        "message": 0.2064,
        "country": "AU",
        "sunrise": 1485720272,
        "sunset": 1485766550
    },
    "id": 2172797,
    "name": "Cairns",
    "cod": 200
}
```

А он не соответствует вашему объекту Weather.

Я вам рекомендую скачать для Android Studio плагин [Robo POGO Generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8634-robopojogenerator/) или же воспользоваться каким-нибудь онлайн сервисом, например [этим](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

P.S. Как правильно заметил Circassian вам так же необходимо поменять протокол в вашей ссылке с `https://` на `http://`

Comment: Для начала ему нужно получить корректный ответ. Он дергает `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=532096` и получает `401`

Comment: Да, это верное замечание, спасибо

Comment: @Circassian Я изменил URL, но теперь приложение как будто вообще не посылает запрос. Пытался вывести ```responce.body()``` через ```Log```, через ```Toast``` - тишина

Comment: Он точно возвращает данные? Проверьте в постмене, да хоть в адресной строке браузера

Comment: @Sergei Buvaka Я немного изменил класс-модель Weather, так как мне не нужны все данные. Мне нужны лишь температура. описание. влажность и местоположение. Использовал я сайт, который вы мне привели, но не стал копировать оттуда все

Comment: @Circassian Да, вовзращает. Я приложил скриншот

Comment: И именно этот url теперь дергаешь retrofit'ом?

Comment: @Circassian, да, именно этот

Comment: @Circassian я получаю только город. Остальные 3 параметра не выводятся

Comment: Уже что-то) Сверяй модели, структуры, названия полей.

Comment: @Circassian  а может причина быть в том, что ```description``` находится внутри ```weather```?. По сути город или ```name``` не находится внутри еще какой-либо структуры. Надеюсь внятно сформулировал)

Comment: Блин, только сейчас обратил внимание. У тебя здесь ожидает на вход список `Call<List<Weather>> getWeather();` но ведь приходит один объект. Нужно так `Call<Weather> getWeather();`

Comment: @Circassian  я это давно исправил)). Вот после исправления этой ошибки и вывелся город

Comment: Кажется я уже близко. Завтра продолжу, сегодня хватит). Вам спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что ты дергаешь

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=532096
```

а не

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Makhachkala&units=metric&APPID=0b08836a21c5d5280dbc3e634a3712a7
```

и получаешь ответ

```
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}
```

который не биндится в твою модель